# Connecting PHP with DB2 on linux

Tags: php, linux, connection, db2

I get a connection failed message when trying to connect to db2 database in php, the code is run on a linux server..

**I have added the instance and extension lines in php.ini**

---

ibm_db2.instance_name=db2inst1

[ibm_db2]

### extension=ibm_db2.so

I am I missing something in the php.ini file or any other file?

**Note I am following the following steps:**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ibm-db2.installation.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ibm-db2.requirements.php

### **I get the following error messages in the httpd/error_log**

[Mon Jun 30 15:35:16 2014] [notice] Digest: done
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/idb_db2.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/idb_db2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Jun 30 15:35:16 2014] [warn] ./mod_dnssd.c: No services found to register
[Mon Jun 30 15:35:16 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jun 30 16:06:05 2014] [error] [client 192.168.48.121] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function db2_connect() in /var/www/html/PhpProject1/index.php on line 14
[Mon Jun 30 16:06:18 2014] [error] [client 192.168.48.121] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function db2_connect() in /var/www/html/PhpProject1/index.php on line 14

---

Comment: I just posted an answer that worked for me over here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31082570/652519

Answer (score 0):

please check this error message:
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/idb_db2.so'
You need to have this library physically on disk. Apparently it´s not true in your case :-)
Please check (for 10.5)
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21385217
and here you can find client+libraries needed (I hope IBM Data Server Runtime Client can solve it).