# IBM-DB2 installtion failed on xampp1.7.1 on linux system

Tags: php, linux, xampp, pecl, ibm-db2

I am trying to install ibm-db2 driver on my lampp server, but I am getting this error:

```
root# /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install ibm_db2
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/ibm_db2"
Cannot initialize 'channel://pecl.php.net/ibm_db2', invalid or missing package file
Package "channel://pecl.php.net/ibm_db2" is not valid
install failed
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ibm-db2.installation.php#89894


Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing the ibm-db2 extension via the link in the comment, however, that didn't work for me. I ended up finding an answer and posted it here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31082570/652519. The only way I could get the drivers was to have the company that setup our IBM i Access server, login to IBM and download the drivers. Then I followed the steps in the above link to install the drivers and make a connection.