# Syntax error in odbc.ini

Tags: php, odbc, ibm-midrange

We're connecting to an old AS400 database through an iSeries linux driver. Everything works fine: we can connect and query the base with no problems, but we'd like to correct this error, as it fills the log file every time the script is run:

```
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in /etc/php.d/odbc.ini on line 14
```

The ini file is included in the script using:

```
putenv('ODBCSYSINI=/etc');  
putenv('ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini');
```

This is the line 14 of the odbc.ini:

```
DefaultPackage          = A/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm..seems to be right out of IBM's example...http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1020437  Are you sure you're looking at the right odbc.ini?

Comment: Someone posted an answer about connecting from Linux to IBM i recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241267/php-linux-to-as-400-db2  Perhaps that will give you some assistance.

Comment: Thanks for the input, it helped me fix some problems in etc/odbc.ini and etc/odbcinst.ini ( it was lacking the [odbc ...] headers ). The php.d/odbc.ini error was caused by erroneus entry ( sysadmin put there the same lines as etc/odbc.ini has had instead of putting 'extension=odbc.so'). So all solved, thanks again.