# Connect to specific DB2 schema with PHP

Tags: php, database, db2, php-5.6

Is there a way to specify the schema to use with PHP's `db2_connect` method? Apparently it connects to the default schema, though it seems like there should be an option to specify schema in the connect string.

Comment: you connect to a db not a schema. can you add some details of what your trying to accomplish

Comment: @Dagon-- then after you connect, you'd set schema as a separate command?

Comment: correct, there's no connect db + select schema in one function. but as below you can defult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this using `db2_connect()`, however, there are other options.

1. Issue the [`set schema` statement](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001016.html?lang=en):

   `db2_exec($yourconnection, 'SET SCHEMA WHATEVER')`
2. Set the default schema in the `db2cli.ini` file using the [`CurrentSchema` keyword](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0008779.html?lang=en).
3. Similarly, use [`CurrentSchema` parameter](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.config.doc/doc/r0054619.html?lang=en) in the `db2dsdriver.cfg` file.

Note that the latter two methods will affect all connections, including those made by other CLI/ODBC applications on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer on SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31082570/652519

It might help get things setup and configured correctly. There is an option in the odbc.ini file called `Default Libraries`. I've never had the need to change this, but this may be what you're looking for.

There's also an option for the database. In the above referenced answer, the `database` value in the odbc.ini file is blank, which I would assume can be changed. Again, I haven't had a need to change it, so you can tinker with it to test.